# Call python script from mysql trigger on 2023

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, triggers

I want to use MySQL trigger to call a Python script

I searched in StackOverflow and I got multiple solutions but that was 4 years ago and that is not working for me

sys_exec throwing error

The third-party library installation process not worked

any other good solution is there?

Comment: I linked to an question about calling a PHP script from a trigger, but the same answer applies to scripts written in Python or any other language.